# Integrate $\int_{|z|<1} \frac{1}{z^k\cos z}dz$ where $k=1,2,3$, for complex

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\mbox{Integrate } \int_{|z|<1} \frac{1}{z^k\cos z}dz \mbox{ where } k \in \mathbb{Z}^+, z \in \mathbb{C}.$$

We have $\frac{1}{\cos z}$ is analytic in $|z| < 1$ and $|z|< 1$ is closed, let $z_{0}=0 $ then by  Cauchy’s Integral Formula and Cauchy’s Integral Formula for Derivatives we have the result. Am I right?

Could you help me, if it is right?

Comment: I assume you mean $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^j \cos(z)}$? And have you tried to solve it using the Residue Theorem?

Comment: How would use it, if we have $\frac{1}{z^icos(z)}$?

Comment: Observe that $\frac{1}{z^j \cos(z)}$ has a pole of order $j$ at $0$. I encourage you to use $j$ instead of $i$ for this integer power since we are dealing with complex analysis and the symbol $i$ already has a very well established meaning in this context.